# Distinguishing a regular file from a symlink

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that needs to distinguish a regular file from a symlink. I thought I could do this with if/test expression, but it doesn't work as I expected to:

```
$ touch regular_file
$ test -f regular_file; echo $?
0
$ test -h regular_file; echo $?
1
$ ln -s regular_file symlink
$ test -h symlink; echo $?
0
$ test -f symlink; echo $?
0
```

Why is that? And, how can I properly do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you are just scrambling your tests a bit. You don't need to run both test, the only one you need for this case is the `-h` one to tell you if the file is a symlink.

```
test -h file && echo "is symlink" || echo "is regular file"
```

The `-f` test you used only tells you if the object is a file or a link to a file. This would return `1` (a failure) if it was a directory, a device node, a symlink to a directory, etc., but will return `0` (a success) if it is a symlink to a file. In other words some symlinks would evaluate to true, others to false.

If you also needed to know if it was a symlink to a file rather than a directory, you would need to combine the results of both tests with a little bit of logic.

Comment: As I understood from the docs, the difference between `-e` and `-f` was that `-e` was used to know if a file (of any type) existed, and `-f` was specifically to test if the file existed and was a regular file. It seems I misunderstood what a "regular file" was..

Comment: @Nupraptor: Yes, you misunderstood the docs. A symlink is considered a regular file as opposed to some of the other types of nodes a file could be (block-device node, character-device node, directory, etc). If you want to know what TYPE of file it is you have to run a file type specific test like `-h` for symlinks, `-p` for named pipes, etc.

Comment: Then, how do I test if a file is a regular file in the sense that is not a pipe nor a symlink, etc? Should I open another question for this?

Comment: @Nupraptor: The only weird case is a symlink that links to a regular file. Otherwise, if it tests as a regular file, it's a regular file.

Comment: test -f directory will return a 1 not a 0: test -f . ; echo $? (outputs 1)

Answer (score 8):

@Caleb is correct about making the script just test for the symlink.  However the part about why was left out and I was curious.  If you look at the coreutils source code and strace the output of test you can see that when you run the symbolic link test it uses lstat and if you using the -f test it actually calls 'stat' which follows the symlink:

```
$ ln -s varnish_config XXX
$ strace -s 2000 test -L XXX 2>&1 | grep XXX
execve("/usr/bin/test", ["test", "-L", "XXX"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
lstat("XXX", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=14, ...}) = 0

$ strace -s 2000 test -L varnish_config 2>&1 | grep varnish
execve("/usr/bin/test", ["test", "-L", "varnish_config"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
lstat("varnish_config", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=1046, ...}) = 0

$ strace -s 2000 test -f XXX 2>&1 | grep XXX
execve("/usr/bin/test", ["test", "-f", "XXX"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
stat("XXX", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=1046, ...}) = 0
```

From the stat man page:

```
   stat() stats the file pointed to by path and fills in buf.

   lstat() is identical to stat(), except that if path is a symbolic link,
   then the link itself is stat-ed, not the file that it refers to.
```

This means the -f test will return true as long as the filename specified is a symlink to a regular file or a regular file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the `test` operators that test file-related things do it *after* symlink resolution `test -f symlink` will return true if `symlink` is a *regular* file determined after symlink resolution, same for `test -s symlink` and non-empty files or `test -d symlink` and directory files or `test -r symlink` for readable files.

It does that using the `stat()` system call.

The only exception is with `-L` (generally preferred over `-h`), which in order to test for the file being a symlink needs to do a `lstat()` to get information about the link itself, not the file it eventually resolves to.

So to check that a file is a *regular* file *before* symlink resolution, you need:

```
if test -f "$file" && test ! -L "$file"; then
  echo is a regular file
fi
```

And to disambiguate between symlink, regular and other types, you'd want to do the `test -L` first:

```
if test -L "$file"; then
  echo symlink
elif test -f "$file"; then
  echo regular # strictly speaking, it could also have been replaced
               # with a symlink to a regular file since the previous test
else
  echo other type or not accessible
fi
```